# How to do image slide over another image when mouse over..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**HTML**

```
<img id="1" src="http://tinyurl.com/ksl52ao"/>
<div class="wrap" id="2">
    <img src="http://tinyurl.com/lgua65m"/>             
    <p class="text_over_image" style="font-size:36px;">TEXT</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrap {
height:auto;
margin: auto;
text-align:center;
position:relative;
}

.text_over_image {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    color:RED;  
    height:0px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#2").hide();

$("#1").mouseover(function(){
    $("#1").hide();
    $("#2").show();
});

$("#2").mouseout(function(){
    $("#2").hide();
    $("#1").show();
});
```

Here I can show hidden image when mouse over another image. But I need to slide second image from bottom to top when mouse over.
[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2L1kb4r5/1/)

Comment: Have you check slideUp and slideDown effect in jquery? http://api.jquery.com/slideup/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply following will give you effect like you need.

```js
     
$(function(){
 $("#container").hover(function(){
  $("img", this).stop().animate({top:"-130px"},{queue:false,duration:200});
 }, function() {
  $("img", this).stop().animate({top:"0px"},{queue:false,duration:200});
 });
});
```

```css
#container {
 margin:100px auto;
 width:909px;
}
#container {
 margin-right:3px;
 float:left;
 width:296px;
 height:130px;
 border:1px solid #999;
 position:relative;
 overflow:hidden;
}
#container img {
 position:absolute;
}
.text_over_image {
    position: absolute;
 margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    color:RED; 
 height:0px;
}

.simg{
    position:relative;
    top:130px;
    left:0;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
 <div class="fimg"><a href="#"><img height="130px" width="100%" src="http://tinyurl.com/ksl52ao" alt="" /></a>
    </div> <div class="simg"> 
    <a href="#"><img height="130px" width="100%" src="http://tinyurl.com/lgua65m" alt="" /><p class="text_over_image" style="font-size:36px;">TEXT</p></a>
    </div>
```

Check [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/2L1kb4r5/6/)

You can check also [Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/2L1kb4r5/7/)

Answer (score 1):

This could be achieved using pure css, eliminating the need for js:

```css
.wrap img {
  height: 100%;
  100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  transition: all 1s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrap img:last-child {
  top: 100%;
}
.wrap:hover img:first-child {
  top: -100%;
}
.wrap:hover img:last-child {
  top: 0;
}
.wrap p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  color: white;
  transition: all 1s;
  z-index: 8;
}
.wrap:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300" />
  <p>some text too</p>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/500" />
</div>
```